# Viewmodel not being passed to controller post method? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm having some problems with returning a viewmodel to my controller's create post method in asp.net 6, the viewmodel seems to always be empty and I've run to a dead end debugging.

I'm trying to upload some images and send them to my post method in the controller.

Specifically the create(ArtImages vm) seems to be null.

If anything is unclear or I need to add anything let me know.

Artwork model:

```
 public class Artwork
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Information { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ArtworkImage> ArtworkImage { get; set; }
    }
```

ArtworkImage model:

```
public class ArtworkImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    public Artwork Artwork { get; set; }
}
```

ArtImages viewmodel:

```
public class ArtImages
{
    public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
    public Artwork Artwork { get; set; }
}
```

Create artworkImages view:

```
@model website.ViewModel.ArtImages

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ArtworkImage</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" encrypte="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="ArtworkImages">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Artwork" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Artwork" asp-items="@ViewBag.images" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Select artwork</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Artwork" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Images" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Images" class="form-control" multiple />
                <span asp-validation-for="Images" class="text-danger"></span>
             </div>
             <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

GET: ArtworkImages/Create:

```
public IActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ArtImages vm = new ArtImages();
        ViewBag.images = new SelectList(_context.Artworks.Where(m => m.Id == id).ToList(), "Id", "Information");
        return View(vm);
    }
```

POST: ArtworkImages/Create:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ArtImages vm)
{
    foreach (var item in vm.Images)
    {
        string stringFileName = UploadFile(item);
        var artworkImage = new ArtworkImage
        {
            ImageURL = stringFileName,
            Artwork = vm.Artwork
        };
        _context.ArtworkImages.Add(artworkImage);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Select Tag Helper `asp-for` specifies the model property name for the select element and `asp-items` specifies the option elements.

   Your select option here generate the data by the following code:

   ```
   ViewBag.images = new SelectList(_context.Artworks.Where(m => m.Id == id).ToList(), "Id", "Information");
   ```

   It will generate the option **text** by `Information` property and option **value** by `Id` property.
2. You **cannot pass whole complex model** by `asp-for`.
3. The backend will receive the **value** of the element.

**In summary:**

The `asp-for` should be `Artwork.Id`.

**Note:**

Besides, you **mispell** `encrypte="multipart/form-data"`, it should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

---

The whole working demo:

View:

```
@model ArtImages

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ArtworkImage</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
                                    //change here.....
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="ArtworkImages">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Artwork" class="control-label"></label>

                        //change here....
                <select asp-for="Artwork.Id" asp-items="@ViewBag.images" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">Select artwork</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Artwork.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Images" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Images" class="form-control" multiple />
                <span asp-validation-for="Images" class="text-danger"></span>
             </div>
             <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]ArtImages vm)
```